# Is binomial(n, k)=0 (mod n) when gcd(n, k)=1? When gcd(n, k)>1?

Tags: algorithms, primes

I was programming the AKS primality test, and I have two questions.

Is it correct that if gcd(n, k)=1, then binomial(n, k)=0 (mod n)?

Is it correct that if gcd(n, k)>1, then binomial(n, k)>0 (mod n)?

Comment: This looks a math question rather than a CS one. (use *then* if not comparing)

Answer (score 1):

All variables are understood to be positive integers. Let $n\mid m$ mean $n$ is a factor of $m$, a.k.a. $m$ is divisible by $n$ or $m=0\pmod n$.

> Is it correct that if $\gcd(n, k)=1$, then $n\mid\binom nk$?

Yes.

Since $k\binom nk=n\binom{n-1}{k-1}$, we know $k\binom nk$ is divisible by $n$. Since $\gcd(n,k)=1$,  we must have $\binom nk$ is divisible by $n$.

---

> Is it correct that if $\gcd(n, k)>1$, then $\binom nk>0\pmod n$?

The relation of "greater than" or "less than" modulo $n$ does not make sense since, for example, $-1=1=2019\pmod 2$.

What you have in mind should be the following question.

> Is it correct that if $\gcd(n, k)>1$, then $n\not\mid\binom nk$?

Not necessarily.

The smallest counterexample is $\gcd(10,4)=2\neq1$ but $10\mid\binom{10}4=210$. In fact, if $n=2\pmod8$, then $n\mid\binom n4$.

---

[Kummer's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kummer%27s_theorem) provides a way to compute the exponent of the highest power of a given prime number dividing a binomial coefficient. Peter Taylor points out that it can be used to determine whether $n\mid\binom nk$ in polynomial time if we know the prime factorisation of $k$ or $n$. However, no algorithm is known to be able to obtain the prime factorisation of an integer in polynomial-time.

Here is a related interesting article, [*divisibility properties of binomial coefficients*](https://www.cambridge.org/core/services/aop-cambridge-core/content/view/2E79D6886C2AB67C1A35BF45E7A70961/S0025557200078888a.pdf/divisibility_properties_of_binomial_coefficients.pdf) by K. R. Mclean.

---

**Exercise 1**. Show that if $m\mid n$ and $\gcd(m,k)=1$, then  $m\mid\binom nk$.

**Exercise 2**. Show that $2i\mid\binom{2i}4$ iff $i=1\pmod4$.

**Exercise 3**. Find infinitely many pairs of $n$ and $k$ such that $1\lt k \mid n$ and $n\mid\binom nk$. (Hint, one such family can be found by setting $k=6$.)